# Zoom control and streetview icons not showing on Google map sample?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am working on showing locations on map by using google maps APIv3. It worked well before now. But currently, zoom control and streetview icons are missing suddenly. I don't know why. Kindly Help me to know the exact reason.

Comment: [issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6858)

Answer (score 1):

The pathing in maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js is wrong. For example in the drawing tools images, https://maps.gstatic.com/openhand_8_8.cur is being used instead of https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur. Suggests some type of recent change by google that has broken it for the meanwhile.

Edit: Google resolved this issue in about one hour